# Errors of nokogiri "Load Error" with docker-compose up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, rubygems, nokogiri

I am running a rails app with docker-compose on a m1 mac.
Kept getting 2 specific errors,

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bootsnap-1.12.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:15:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
```

This is the first one

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.13.6-aarch64-linux/lib/nokogiri/extension.rb:7:in `require_relative': Error loading shared library ld-linux-aarch64.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.13.6-aarch64-linux/lib/nokogiri/3.1/nokogiri.so) - /usr/local/bundle/gems/nokogiri-1.13.6-aarch64-linux/lib/nokogiri/3.1/nokogiri.so (LoadError)
```

This is the second one.

The errors started showing after all the gems are installed, I have reinstalled nokogiri countless times, rebuilt the image and container, and made sure bundle installs in my dockerfile as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with an [Alpine-based](https://www.alpinelinux.org) image, a possible solution is to install the [gcompat](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/armhf/gcompat) package. You can do this by executing the following command:

```bash
$ apk add gcompat
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem was resolved by adding `platform: linux/x86_64` into my `docker-compose.yml` file